# fixed Footer In PhoneGap For Windows Phone7

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

Can anyone recommend the best method to create a fixed footer nav bar within a HTML5 Windows Phone7 Phone gap app?

Answer (score 0):

This is not WP7 specific but I recommend you use a framework like Jquery Mobile which makes creating fixed footers pretty simple.

[Demo](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html)

Comment: Thank You For Your Comments. But My Problem IS I'm Developing App in Windows7 I need A fixed Footer It means When I'm Scroll The Body I need Footer Not Changing it's Position Footer In Same Place Only Body Content Must Be Go Up And Down.